How to show the following sequence of group homomorphism to be exact?
Background
The following is taken from:  Graduate Course In Algebra, A - Volume 1
by: Ioannis Farmakis and Martin Moskowitz
....a short exact sequence of groups is just another way of talking about a normal subgroup and the corresponding quotient group.  However, even if $H$ is normal in $G$, knowing $H$ and $G/H$ does not determine $G$.  Here is an example:
$$0\xrightarrow{f_1}\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{f_2}\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{f_3}\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{f_4}0$$
Questions:
I want to ask about how to show the above sequence as exact.
For the element $0$, is it actually $0$ or is it $p\mathbb{Z}$?
For a sequence of maps to be exact, we need $\text{Im }f_{i-1}=\text{ker }f_{i}$.
For the first pair of maps $f_1, f_2$, we have $f_1(0)=p\mathbb{Z}$, and $\text{Im }f_1=\{p\mathbb{Z}\}$.  For the map $f_2$, we define it to be $f_2(n+p\mathbb{Z})=n+p^2\mathbb{Z}$.  So for $n=p^2$, $f_2(p^2+p\mathbb{Z})=p^2+p^2\mathbb{Z}=p^2\mathbb{Z}$ and $p^2+p\mathbb{Z}=p+p\mathbb{Z}=p\mathbb{Z}$.  So $f_2(p^2+p\mathbb{Z})=f_2(p\mathbb{Z})=p^2\mathbb{Z}$, which implies $\text{ker }f_2=\{p\mathbb{Z}\}$, so $\text{Im }f_1=\text{ker }f_2$.
For the second pair of maps $f_2, f_3$, we define the $f_3$ map to be $f_3(n+p^2\mathbb{Z})=n+p\mathbb{Z}$.  Now the image of $f_2$ is $f_2(n+p^2\mathbb{Z})=n+p\mathbb{Z}$.  For the kernel of $f_3$, we have $f_3(p+p^2\mathbb{Z})=p+p\mathbb{Z}=p\mathbb{Z}$.  The kernel of $f_3$ seem to be $\{p+p^2\mathbb{Z}\}$ Here I am not sure how to make image of $f_2$ to equal to kernel $f_3$.
For the last pair of maps $f_3, f_4$, we define $f_4$ to be $f_4(n+p\mathbb{Z})=0$.  From $f_3(n+p^2\mathbb{Z})=n+p\mathbb{Z}$, it's image is $\{n+p\mathbb{Z}\}$, and the kernel of $f_4$ is $\text{ker }f_4=\{n+p\mathbb{Z}\}$.  Hence $\text{Im }f_3=\text{ker }f_4$.

You can just take the canonical projection for $f_3.$  $f_2$ is the inclusion.

Right.   $G$ can also be $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z×\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z.$  In that case they say the exact sequence is left split.

@calcll I am not familar with the term left split.  Can you elaborate please?  I am familar with the term split sequence.

It actually the terminology "split", I think,  is because you have a direct product. If it's left split it's actually also right split.    In terms of the sequence,  there are maps going to the left whose compositions with $f_2,f_3,$ respectively,  are the identity.

See, $\Bbb Z/p^2\Bbb Z$ doesn't split.   It's cyclic.

It may not be needed but if you want to be sure you understood, you can try to show that we have an exact sequence: $$0 \to \mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/mn \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/m \mathbb{Z} \to 0$$

I need to be careful here.   If $n$ is composite,  $\Bbb Z_n$ can sometimes  in a sense  still split,  by the Chinese remainder theorem.  Nevertheless "splitting" is a reference to being able to write as a product. The lingo is suggestive.
